# What is the best way to re-factor a variable name in vim?

Tags: substitute, ide

I know there is one way to search and replace variable occurrences across a source file.

But is there any better way by which if I rename a variable at one place it gets renamed at other places as well without search and replace or substitute?

Comment: The answer will depend on the language. In some codebases, it may be practical to write a regex that precisely matches your situtation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just use the usual workflow `search` and `replace`:

```
/original
cwreplaced
n.n.
```

---

You can take also advantage of the `gn` motion:

```
/original<CR>
cgnreplaced<ESC>
.....
```

`cgn` will `c`hange the `n`ext matched pattern, so instead of using `n.n.` to `go to next` and `repeat` you can just `..` which means `replace next`.

`gn` means "search for next occurence and start a visual selection over it", you can read more about it on the doc: `:h gn`.

Comment: Can you please explain about gn motion? I am quite new to vim.

Comment: Always ask Vim first: `:help gn`.

Comment: @nobe4 : You can improve your answer. :) User might want to replace with all $first with $second, not $first_variable. Can we go with \<pattern\>? Or, suggest a better way!

Comment: @WitVault Instead of typing the word you are going to replace, you can just use search with `#` and `*`. With `:set hlsearch` you will see what is highlighted and then do usual `cgn` thing.

Comment: @SibiCoder you can use `t` or `f` motion to replace prefix you want and `n.` to move to the next occurance

Answer (score 7):

You can use a substitute:

```
:%s/original/replaced/g
```

Will `s`ubstitute across the entire file (`%`) `original` by `replaced`. And will replace multiple occurrences on the same line `g`.

If you are not confident about automatically replacing, you can add the `c` flag to ask for confirmation each time.

Comment: I do not want to blindly to search and replace.

Comment: Then the `c` flag is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add another option.

You can do `/original` and then do `:%s//replacement`.
(Use `/c` at the end if you want confirmation).

Although you are pressing 3 more keys, this has an advantage over doing just `%s/original/replacement` because it provides a visual cue that your search is correct.