# How can I repeat the cgn sequence?

Tags: search, replace

Recently I learned the awesome command `cgn` to repeat a change to a word. I’ve seen several answers advising its use, like this:

[What is the best way to re-factor a variable name in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/what-is-the-best-way-to-re-factor-a-variable-name-in-vim/8288#8288)

and this:

[How to find and replace in Vim without having to type the original word?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13689/how-to-find-and-replace-in-vim-without-having-to-type-the-original-word/13701#13701)

But the problem is that I can't add a repeat prefix to it. If I have, say, 10-20 occurrences, and I want to change them all, it's rather anoying to type 20 dots. If I add a prefix it jumps the lines and changes only one occurence, instead of repeating the whole change.

I can add a macro:

```
/foo<cr>qacgnbar<esc>.q20@a
```

But it's 5 keystrokes more. Well.. it's better than 10 or 20 keystrokes, but I thought there could be a better option.

How can I repeat cgn a number of times ?

Comment: `:%s//\=@./g` if you've already searched (`/`) for "foo" and changed (`c`) it to "bar" earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I repeat cgn a number of times ?

Try this mapping:

```
nno <expr> <leader>. '<esc>' . repeat('.', v:count1)
```

The purpose of `<esc>` is to cancel the count.  For example, if you press:

```
3 <leader>.
```

in the typeahead buffer, `<leader>.` is expanded into `...`, and the resulting sequence is:

```
3...
```

`3.` makes Vim execute `3cgn`; that is replace the third occurrence of the search register.
This behavior is documented at `:h .`:

> Simple changes can be repeated with the "." command.  Without a count, the
> count of the last change is used.  **If you enter a count, it will replace the
> last one.**  |v:count| and |v:count1| will be set.

But:

- that's not what you want
- the count is not needed in that position, since `repeat()` already uses it later to repeat `.` as many times as desired

Btw, if `<esc>` triggers an audible/visual bell, try to replace it with `<c-\><c-n>` (see `:h CTRL-\_CTRL-N`):

```
nno <expr> <leader>. '<c-\><c-n>' . repeat('.', v:count1)
```

---

For more info, see:

```
:h map-<expr>
:h repeat()
:h v:count1
```

Comment: Thanks :) about the :hs but I already understood the whole line. We discussed your solution in a Telegram group about VIM that I'm in. You used '<esc>' to return to normal mode instead of :normal in order to avoid the substitution of count by a range. Then you included the first dot in order to be able to repeat the operation, but that moves the count value which were in v:count to v:count1, so you have to call repeat on v:count1. Is that it ?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less the explanation; I updated the answer to give more details.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. About "Btw, if <esc> triggers an audible/visual bell", it doesn't but again thanks.

Comment: The only problem is that I was wrong: that version won't work with Vrapper. Only the first one I posted works

Answer (score 1):

Your macro actually does unnecessary work, since it does `cgn` and `.` on every invocation.

```
/foo<CR>cgnfoo<Esc>qa.q
```

Isn’t really any shorter, but it does have the advantage of being easier to use with a count and also separating the action from the repeat.

Comment: Personally i don’t mind several dots but that’s me

Answer (score 0):

A user in a Telegram group dedicated to VIM showed me a very good solution:

```
:nnoremap <leader>. :normal .<cr>
```

this remaps `<leader>.` to allow a prefix with repeat count. In my case  is mapped to the default value `\`
So I just type say `10\.` and it repeats `cgn` 10 times.

It even works in Eclipse's Vrapper.

But if anyone has a better solution I'd like to hear.

Comment: It won't work as expected when you have several matches on the same line.  That's because when you hit a count, it's translated into a range.  And when `:norm` is prefixed by a range, the cursor is automatically positioned on the first column of each line in the range.  IOW, after executing each `.`, `:norm` repositions the cursor on the next line. See `:h :normal-range`. Also, even if it worked, you would probably want a bang: `:norm!`. In any case, try this instead: `nno <expr> <leader>. '<esc>'..repeat('.', v:count1)`.

Comment: @user938271 I got an erro trying what you said: `5: Expressão inválida: .repeat('.', v:count1)
E15: Expressão inválida: '^['..repeat('.', v:count1) `.  "Expressão inválida" is portuguese for "invalid expression". I don't have any experience in the keymap thing. If I needed to translate something, please clarify. Better still if you could create an answer with your solution. I confirm that it doesn't work with 2 targets in the same line.

Comment: You probably use an old Vim version which doesn't support the concatenation operator `..`; replace it with a single dot `.`.

Comment: @user938271 worked fine. Including VRapper. Thanks. Don't you want to create an answer so I can accept/upvote it ?